# Joining records from two tables that are not completely identical

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-joins

I am trying to join a table and a shapefile using ArcGIS 10.2.1 and I need some help. The table has simple records similar to this one:
OID1 WORK1
1   XW-02600
2   LL-02608
3   PM-02609
4   GL-02610
5   GL-01894
6   XW-01895
7   PM-01884

The shapefile has some concatenated records:

OID2 WORK2
1    XW-02607 / GL-01894
2    PM-02609 / GL-01894
3    PM-01896 / XW-01895
4    GL-02610
5    LL-02608
6    XW-02607 / GL-01894
7    GL-02610

The table and shapefile I have is much more complex than the example above, the table has much less records than the shapefile. The shapefile has many records with concatenated values.

All the records in the table should be in the shapefile (but not vice versa), a simple join will not join anything after the "/". I would like for the join to be able work regardless of being behind the "/".

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need a record for each or if the forward slash is the only issue. but if it is just dealing with the forward slash, try this.

Add a new field to your shapefile and enter this is field calculator:

!SOURCEFIELDHERE!.replace(chr(47),"")

Then do a copy of your field in Excel and do a find/replace and replace the forward slashes with nothing.

Make your join based on these new fields.

I have a feeling you what you really want is to create singular records on either side... but maybe this is all you need.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I just wanted to know if joining without creating a new record or removing the slash is possible. In my actual shapefile I have records with multiple slashes (LL-02608 /  XW-02607 / GL-01894 / GL-02610), which makes joining on the new field a bit of a hassle if I have multiple new fields. Would you know how to create a new record? Thanks so much for your help!